# Retrieving the number of physical core processors

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, multicore, processor

I know I can use `System.Environment.ProcessorCount` to return the number of "processors" in a machine. What I am trying to do is find out if there is a way to determine the number of cores in the processor, not including hyperthreading as a "core". For example, on a dual core hyperthreading processor, `System.Environment.ProcessorCount` will return 4 because there are 2 physical cores, both with hyperthreading. What I want to do is return 2 because there are only 2 physical cores.

I am using C#, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WMI to obtain the number of cores in the system. This similar question on stack overflow includes a code sample: -->  [How to find the Number of CPU Cores via .NET/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c)

An important point to keep in mind is that in certain systems this value may not be available; for example, on windows server 2003 you need to download a hotfix from Microsoft to get "NumberOfCores" to work.