# detect how many cores a client has using C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore

I am creating a program that will multiple background tasks simultaneously. I would like to create a number of threads to do these based on the number of cores that a client is running. So that if they are using a multi-core processor, the program will run faster. Is there any way to have C# check how many cores a processor has? Finding model of the processor would also work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the Number of CPU Cores via .NET/C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Environment.ProcessorCount`, although I would avoid this sort of optimization because the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) takes care of it for you.