# In c# windows How to limit the number of executions on a core processor?

Tags: c#, multithreading, multicore, execution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multi threading which would be the best to use? (Threadpool or threads)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628843/multi-threading-which-would-be-the-best-to-use-threadpool-or-threads)

There is significant edits in this question so please read in its entirety.

Hopefully this is a better question than my previous. I have a .exe which I will be passing different parameters (file paths) to which it will then take in and parse. So I will have a loop going, looping through the file paths in a list and passing them to this .exe file.

For this to be more efficient, I want to spread the execution across multiple cores which I think you do through threading.

My question is, should I use the threadpool, or multiple threads to run this .exe asynchronously?

Also, depending on which one of those you guys think is the best, if you can point me to a tutorial that will have some info on what I want to do. Thank you!

EDIT: I need to limit the number of executions of the .exe to ONE execution PER CORE. This is the most efficient because if I am parsing 100,000 files I can't just fire up 100000 processes. So I am using threads to limit the number of executions at one time to one execution per core. If there is another way (other than threads) to find out if a processor isn't tied up in execution, or if the .exe has finished please explain. But if there isn't another way, my FINAL question is how would I use a thread to call a parse method and then call back when that thread is no longer in use?