# c# to see how many CPU sockets are in the system with CPU and without?

Tags: c#, hardware, cpu

I need to know if the server (motherboard) has more than one socket even if there is one CPU on it with the help of C#!

is there a way?

Comment: Do you know the type of motherboard? And is this a general purpose application, or very specific for your server-farm?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c

Comment: it's general, mostly for servers, HP,Dell, IBM, .....

Comment: @Massimiliano Peluso, I have this covered, but I need to know the Sockets on the motherboard and possible to use, not how many installed already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should dig into [WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Where is plenty of articles how to access and use WMI from .net. The only problem is to find right data table.

As it seems this is not an easy (if possible) task to get this kind of information. Most certanly you can't get number of sockets if no CPU installed in all of the sockets. See [this note on subject](http://www.sql-server-pro.com/physical-cpu-count.html).

Comment: Seems like @Massimiliano in comments even found exact duplice of what you want.

Comment: Different question.  This is a question (I think) about # of sockets on the motherboard, not what CPUs (& cores) are installed.

Comment: same as Joe said, I need to know if the server has 2 sockets and only one CPU was installed!