# Find Number of CPUs and Cores per CPU using Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, software-design

I am trying to retrieve the Number of CPUs and Cores per CPU using Command Prompt.
I have executed the following command:

`wmic cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors/Format:List`

I get this error: `wmic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I am executing this on a Windows Server 2008 R2 machine.  I believe the 'wmic' command is compatible on this windows.

The directory I am running the command promt from is 'C:\Windows>

Any advice please?

Comment: Is `C:\Windows\System32\Wbem` on your path, and is there actually a file `C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe`?

Comment: if you need the count of physical CPUs, use `wmic computersystem get numberofprocessors`

Comment: @MichaelBurr I just have literally 'C:\Windows>wmic cpu get NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors/Format:List

There is a filepath that leads to C:\Windows\System32\wbem\WMIC.exe

Comment: @MichaelBurr I changed the directory to C:\Windows\System32\Wbem and now the command works. Thanks! Do you want to post as answer so I can accept?

Comment: To include even the CPU information you got to be running `wmic cpu get SocketDesignation, NumberOfCores, NumberOfLogicalProcessors /Format:List`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based upon your comments - your `path` statement has been changed/is incorrect or the `path` variable is being incorrectly used for another purpose.

Answer (score 110):

You can use the environment variable `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` for the total number of processors:

```
echo %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%
```

Comment: Does this environment variable exist on all versions of Windows??? That is incredibly useful.  Are you aware of it's OS version compatibility?

Comment: I only found that it was introduced in Windows 2000/NT. I guess it exists in every Windows desktop and server version after Windows 2000.

Comment: This delivers the total Number of Cores but not the number of CPUs.

Comment: I confirmed that this shows the total number of cores across all sockets

Comment: This is not total number of cores in my hp Windows 10 Pro desktop pc. It is number of Logical processors. My pc has 6 cores and 12 processors so it gives 12. Is anyone knows how can I get that number 6 (number of cores)?

Comment: This is not working windows or linux... I have received empty in windows and linux both. Why it is ?

Comment: This does not appear to be defined in my Powershell session. It just echoes the string %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%.

Comment: @ESilk, in PowerShell you must use `$env:NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS` - see the conceptual [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Environment_Variables) help topic.

Answer (score 10):

You can also enter `msinfo32` into the command line.

It will bring up all your system information. Then, in the find box, just enter `processor` and it will show you your cores and logical processors for each CPU. I found this way to be easiest.

Comment: Not really getting the information on the command line, though ;-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find how many processors (or CPUs) a machine has the same way `%NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS%` shows you the number of cores, save the following script in a batch file, for example, `GetNumberOfCores.cmd`:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('wmic cpu get NumberOfCores /value ^| find "="') do set %%f
```

And then execute like this:

```
GetNumberOfCores.cmd

echo %NumberOfCores%
```

The script will set a environment variable named `%NumberOfCores%` and it will contain the number of processors.

Comment: When executing on the command line I had to replace the double `%%` with single `%`. Like: `for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('wmic cpu get NumberOfCores /value ^| find "="') do set %f`

Answer (score 0):

In order to check the absence of physical sockets run:

```
wmic cpu get SocketDesignation
```

Comment: this command returns `CPU 1`. What do you mean by absence of physical sockets? A CPU can't be present on a motherboard without a socket isn't it? I believe this command simply tells you the number of CPU sockets on your machine.