# Is the processorid per core?

Tags: c#, processor

Can a processor whether a dual core or i3 or i5 or i7 have a processor id equals to number of core processor or number of logical processor?

I am using win32_processor to get processorid.

It returs a processorid but i am in stuck that whether it returns multiple processorid for each core processor or logical processor.

OR, it just return a processor id regardless of number of core processor and logical processor.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the Number of CPU Cores via .NET/C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to test this on your system as it depends on the type of CPU you have. It's likely to be one entry per logical (hyper-threaded) processor.

Here is what [msdn says](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> On a multiprocessor computer, one instance of the Win32_Processor
> class exists for each processor.
>
> To determine the total number of
> processor instances associated with a computer system object, use the
> Win32_ComputerSystemProcessor association class.
>
> To determine if
> hyperthreading is enabled for the processor, compare
> NumberOfLogicalProcessors and NumberOfCores. If hyperthreading is
> enabled in the BIOS for the processor, then NumberOfCores is less than
> NumberOfLogicalProcessors. For example, a dual-processor system that
> contains two processors enabled for hyperthreading can run four
> threads or programs[ <strike>or simultaneously</strike>]. In this case, NumberOfCores is
> 2 and NumberOfLogicalProcessors is 4.