# Getting the maximum concurrent executables at runtime in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I have a SSIS package that is executing some SQL task over a big list of servers. Since the number is quite big I am trying to split the workload and make it process in parallel. The problem is that I need to know exactly in how many parts I can split it, depending on the number of Logical Processors of the machine that runs it.

Is there any way to get the number of logical processors in SSIS so the work can be organized based on that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C# script task returning System.Environment.ProcessorCount , https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.processorcount.aspx .

Or if you want the more specific details, it looks like you need to execute WMI queries, [How to find the Number of CPU Cores via .NET/C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1542213/how-to-find-the-number-of-cpu-cores-via-net-c) .

Comment: I am aware that I can get those details with a C# script, but I was wondering if there is any way of getting them from SSIS.

Comment: You can try the WMI data reader task, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141744.aspx . I don't think it's exposed into any easier component in SSIS.