# Get CPU information without using WMI

Tags: .net, cpu, wmi

The [System.Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class uses WMI (windows Management Instrumentation) to fetch system information. WMI can fail sometimes, making the calls throw [ManagementException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.managementexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Is there an alternative to WMI? I do not need much really; here is the CPU information I need:

```
    Private Sub GetNumberOfProcessors()
        For Each item In New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT NumberOfProcessors FROM Win32_ComputerSystem").Get
            _NumberOfPhysicalProcessors = CInt(item("NumberOfProcessors"))
        Next
        For Each item In New System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors FROM Win32_Processor").Get
            _NumberOfPhysicalCores = CInt(item("NumberOfCores"))
            _NumberOfLogicalCores = CInt(item("NumberOfLogicalProcessors"))
        Next
    End Sub
```

If not, I suppose catching the exception and use [System.Environment.ProcessorCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount?view=net-6.0) as a fall back when that happens could be a worst-case scenario viable option.

**EDIT**: it seems [System.Environment.ProcessorCount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.processorcount?view=net-6.0) is not an option after all, as it relies on WMI too.

Comment: It'd be interesting to know what calls of yours are actually failing and for what stated reasons. If there were some other mechanism that was magically more reliable, why do you think WMI wouldn't be changed to make use of that other mechanism?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I can't easily reproduce the error on my end. Part of the call stack I received goes like this: System.Management.ManagementException: Invalid class 
   at System.Management.ManagementException.ThrowWithExtendedInfo(ManagementStatus errorCode)
   at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext()
I don't need magic, just an alternative when that exception is thrown.

Comment: (exception occurs in the CTor when I call the above code.)

Answer (score 2):

If you were only interested in logical processor, `Environment.ProcessorCount` would have helped. Since you need more details, then P/Invoke can help. You can make use of [GetLogicalProcessorInformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-getlogicalprocessorinformation) function in `Kernel32.dll` to get the details.

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63744912) shows how to get the details.